# Special grid css responsive

Tags: css, grid, responsive

Is it possible to make that sort of grid responsive ? See image below.

I have tried to make all blocks with position absolute, but when I try to make it responsive it doesn't work...

I prefer to mention that the style will be writed dynamically with a php script.

```html
 <img class="responsive" src="01.png"style="position:absolute;">
 <img class="responsive" src="02.png" style="position:absolute;margin-left: 168px;">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

[image: Image grid responsive]

Answer (score 0):

You can try "flexbox magic" but I guess it will too complicated markup to mantaine it